# How to set language in Tess4J using language from mobile device?

Tags: java, tesseract, tess4j

I am using a web service to read image files and return me some text on it using Tesseract.

As we know Tesseract/Tess4j supports languages input in the **ISO 639-3** format (ie: **eng**, **spa**, **deu**, **ara**, etc...) but the language I get from the mobile device comes in this format: **en-gb**, **pt-br**,...

My user can be using any language and request a picture reading.

My question is: anybody has any ideia how to solve this?

And more, if I don't set any language, does it guess/find the language on the image?

Comment: why don't you just convert the language type before setting it in tess4j?

Answer (score 5):

> My question is: anybody has any ideia how to solve this?

convert / find the correct language using something like this

```
    for (Locale locale : Locale.getAvailableLocales()) {
        System.out.println("" + locale
                + "; display: " + locale.getDisplayLanguage()
                + "; name: " + locale.getDisplayName()
                + "; lang: " + locale.getLanguage()
                + "; iso3: " + locale.getISO3Language());
    }
```

Then you can set it in tess4j.

[Ref for the above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29632856/4712391)

> And more, if I don't set any language, does it guess/find the language on the image?

I believe a default value should be set otherwise it will throw an error. (Have not gone through the source code)